# @Model... No imprime dato en el cshtml pero si lo trae de la BD

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo un solucion con 2 proyecto

**1. Web Service**

**2. ASP.NET (MVC)**

En  la vista tengo un input `type="date"` donde escojo una fecha y mediante la comunicacion con el WS tiene que buscar en una BD los registros que en su columna fecha su dato concuerde con esa fecha que introduje en la vista.

***HomeController***

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string date)//Recibe la fecha del input type date
        {
            SearchDate lst = new SearchDate();
            SearchDateResponse lstR = new SearchDateResponse();

            lst.StartDate = date;

            var r = await _servicio_api.Lista(lst.StartDate);
          
            lstR.factura = r;
            
            lst.lstR = lstR;

            return View(lst);
        }
```

***SERVICIO_API e interfaz IServicio_API***

```
//Carpeta Services del ASP.NET
    public async Task<List<Factura>> Lista(string date)//recibe la fecha desde el controller "HomeController" var r = await _servicio_api.Lista(lst.StartDate);
            {
                List<Factura> facturaList = new List<Factura>();
                GetFacturaRequest req = new GetFacturaRequest();
                req.fecha = date;
    
                var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseUrl);        
    
                var response = await client.PostAsync("/api/Factura", content);
    
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var json_respuesta = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    List<Factura> resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Factura>>(json_respuesta);
                    facturaList.AddRange(resultado);
                }
                return facturaList;
            }



    public interface IServicio_API
    {
        Task<List<Factura>> Lista(string date);
    }
```

**FacturaController en el WS**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(GetFacturaRequest date)//recibe la fecha (date) de Servicio_API
        {
            return Ok(facturaService.Get(date));//Le envia la fecha al metodo Get de FacturaService
        }
```

***FactureServices.cs (Carpeta Services en el WS)***

```
 public IEnumerable<Factura> Get(GetFacturaRequest datos)//recibe la fecha de "api/Factura" en FacturaController.cs
        {
            return context.Facturas.Where(x => x.fechaEmision == DateTime.Parse(datos.fecha));
            //Busca cuantos registros en la base de datos existen con la fecha introducida en el input
        }
    }
    public interface IFactura
    {
        IEnumerable<Factura> Get(GetFacturaRequest datos);
    }
```

Luego de aquí vuelve a el `if` del segundo fragmento de código que subí o sea este:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   var json_respuesta = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   List<Factura> resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Factura>>(json_respuesta);
   facturaList.AddRange(resultado);
}
return facturaList;
```

Aquí lo que hace es que evalúa si la petición al servicio fue un true, devuelve los registros si es que encontró o no. (Si hubieran problemas de conexión con el WS se salta el `if` y termina la ejecución)

[image: Aquí se ve que encontró 2 registros]

Y para terminar vuelve al inicio y retorna la fecha que introduje y los registros que encontró con esa fecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya luego cuando intento imprimir en este caso la fecha que trae el `ViewModel` a la vista tal parece como si lo trajera pero no se muestra, o sea en la imagen siguiente se ve que la fecha esta en el @Model... en la etiqueta pero cuando termina la ejecución el dato no se muestra en la vista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al final intento hacer 2 cosas:

1. En la ultima imagen la fecha (StarDate) quiero imprimirla en la vista
2. Si es posible `Count = 2` imprimirlo también ya que viene siendo la cantidad de registros que se encontraron en la BD con esa fecha.

**ViewModel en la vista**

```
@model PORTAL.ViewModels.SearchDate //ViewModel
```

Comment: No será un tema de css?? Si inspeccionas en el navegador y buscas donde debería ir StartDate, que te aparece?

Comment: Viene vacío así: <b></b>